# Forbidden ошибка при установке OpenCart Store на локальную машину

Tags: php, mysql, apache, opencart

На linux машине установил apache2, php5, mysql, задал имя и пароль пользователя при установке, дополнительно поставил phpmyadmin - он работает без проблем, значит mysql и php работает.

apache2 радостно выдает

> It works!

Создал виртуальный сервер, задал ему имя `test`, в папку `/var/www/test.com/public_html` сложил установочные файлы `OCstore`.

Теперь на самом начальном моменте - при подключении к `test` - ошибка

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /install/index.php on this server.

Права к файлам задал в соответствии с рекомендациями из `INSTALL.txt`. Хеллоуворлды на html отлично выдаются из той же папки, а вот установочник не запускается.

**Добавлено** рекурсивно поставил всем папкам и файлам права 755, установка заработала, но на втором шаге установочник жалуется на отстутствие прав на запись. Поставить 777? Безопасно ли это?

Comment: пакет с модулем php для apache установлен? модуль php включен?

Comment: поставьте 766  - запись разрешена, выполнение только для root.

Comment: ещё важно от какого пользователя запускается сервер, в общем случае должен быть www-data для apache2

Comment: @АлексейСтародубцев как я уже писал выше, установщик заработал, но требовал прав на запись в эти файлы. Так как файлам уже было выставлено 755, значит доступ производился от пользователя системы. Как делать, чтобы доступ был от рута? Вопрос, в общем то, скорее на развитие, так как я поставил требуемым файлам 777 и всё заработало.

Comment: добавьте apache2 в группу www-data, если не сработает - смотрите конфигурацию, там может быть указано

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема из-за того, что пользователь ОС из под которого работает apache и выполняются PHP скрипты не добавлен в группу пользователя из под которого Вы загружаете файлы приложения на сервер. В большинстве случаев apache выполняется из под пользователя "www-data", при этом разработчик создает директории приложения и загружает файлы из под другого пользователя ("root", "ubuntu", "admin" и т.д.). Поэтому, когда apache обрабатывает запрос на сайт у PHP нет нужных прав доступа.

Для исправления этой проблемы можно добавить пользователя "www-data" в группу пользователя из под которого Вы загружаете файлы на сервер:

```
usermod -a -G admin www-data
```

И создавать директории приложения сайта с правами 0775 (владелец и все пользователи группы могут делать все, что угодно).

Разумеется, настройки Вашего сервера могут быть совсем другими.

Если ручная настройка сервера дается не легко, то можно использовать готовые решения. Есть очень простая, бесплатная и **правильно работающая** панель управления [VESTA](https://vestacp.com/). Вся базовая установка в 2 строчки консольных команд.